# Pod spec lint fail validation: no known class method for selector

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm trying to create a pod, my framework is building fine and I have no problem using it projects, but when I am trying to convert it into a pod and run `pod spec lint` to validate it it fails, and gives me the following error:

```
 - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  SimpleCameraFramework/SimpleCameraFramework/AVCaptureSession+Safe.m:28:67: error: no known class method for selector 'safeCastFromObject:'
```

In this file I have no compiler error, I have exposed the category in the umbrella header, so I really don't see where the problem is... Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem, for some reason the pod doesn't work with the precompiled header, if I remove it and import the .h file directly in `AVCaptureSession+Safe`, it works...